# Looping with Multiple Parameters without the for loop

Tags: r

Below is a micro-version of my data set. I would like to loop through the three variables without using the 'for' function.

Reproducible Version of the Subject Data Set

```
cat1 <- rep(c("A","S"),each=40)# First variable
cat2 <- rep(c("C","M","Y","K"), each=10, times=2) # Second variable
num1 <- rep(c(0,10,20,30,40,45,65,80,90,100),8) # Third variable
rspns <-structure(list(dataSet = c(0.2484375, 0.3959375, 0.4875, 0.57875, 0.6696875, 0.694375,
    0.816875, 0.879375, 0.9121875, 0.93125, 0.25125, 0.3796875, 0.4609375, 0.5396875, 0.6159375,
    0.6515625, 0.7696875, 0.8384375, 0.864375, 0.8865625, 0.271875, 0.39875, 0.4821875,
    0.5628125, 0.6284375, 0.650625, 0.7553125, 0.8003125, 0.8103125, 0.8125, 0.251875, 0.3775,
    0.4703125, 0.5725, 0.6996875, 0.7378125, 0.945, 1.055625, 1.1021875, 1.1140625, 0.25125,
    0.4203125, 0.5215625, 0.615625, 0.71, 0.74, 0.865625, 0.9246875, 0.9603125, 0.9734375,
    0.256875, 0.3953125, 0.4775, 0.5528125, 0.62875, 0.65875, 0.78375, 0.8384375, 0.8653125,
    0.8740625, 0.2790625, 0.4215625, 0.515, 0.6009375, 0.6665625, 0.693125, 0.7959375, 0.83875,
    0.8490625, 0.8575, 0.2571875, 0.3759375, 0.4665625, 0.56375, 0.68875, 0.725, 0.9259375,
    1.0328125, 1.085625, 1.1096875)), .Names = "rspns",
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -80L))
gain <- data.frame(cat1,cat2,num1, rspns=rspns)

tint <-  function(x,y,z) gain[cat1 == x & cat2 == y & num1 == z, 4]
dgain <- function(x,y,z){(100* (1-10^-(tint(x,y,z) - tint(x,y,0))) / (1-10^-(tint(x,y,100)- tint(x,y,0)))) - z}
```

How can I get the `dgain` function, which takes three parameters, to loop through `cat1`, `cat2` and `num1` variables without using `for` loops?

Your help and technical expertise is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just use `dgain(cat1,cat2,num1)` ?

Comment: @juba I think your `mapply` answer was actually ok (i.e. I'm not sure their function is already vectorized).

Comment: @joran Thanks, but I deleted my answer because it seems that both give the same values.

Comment: juba/joran, i am interested in the mapply and sapply answers, can you please re-post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the basic idea of what I was getting at with my comments:

```
#With a basic for loop for reference
out1 <- rep(NA,80)
for (i in 1:80){
    out1[i] <- dgain(cat1[i],cat2[i],num1[i])
}

out2 <- mapply(dgain,x = cat1,y = cat2,z = num1)

out3 <- dgain(cat1,cat2,num1)

all.equal(out1,unname(out2))
[1] TRUE
> all.equal(out1,out3)
[1] "Mean relative difference: 0.2579067"
```

It's probably possible to refactor your code such that the final idiom (`dgain(cat1,cat2,num1)`) would return the correct result, but it would take more tinkering than I have time for. The issue is that you're subsetting a data frame from your global environment inside one of your functions using `==`, which won't return what you want if you pass is vector arguments.

Nothing special is going on with `mapply`. It's almost literally doing the same thing as the for loop, only perhaps slightly more efficiently and perhaps in a more aesthetically pleasing manner.

Comment: joran, you are correct, the idiom (dgain(cat1,cat2,num1)) does not provide the correct answer. That is why I am interested in mapply or sammply. How should i rewrite the functions? Inputting the three parameters in the current functions manually provides the correct answer. Can you please outline what i should be doing?

Comment: @RagyIsaac I showed you the `mapply` solution. I'm not really interested in re-writing your code for you. You'll probably have to use `match` instead of `==` inside `tint`, though.

Comment: Thanks joran, this help me quite a bit